# Extend an action in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

i have installed this package for Yii2 few days ago: [mdmsoft/yii2-admin](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin)

It's work like a module and it's register in the config of the common application (I work with advanced template).

Now I wanted to extend an action of a controller inside this module and after the view rendered by this action. This is my actual code, i have extended the controller that i want to override in backend app and this is my config in common/config/main.php:

```
<?php
return [
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm' => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],
        'user' => [
            //'class' => 'mdm\admin\models\User',
            'identityClass' => 'mdm\admin\models\User',
            'loginUrl' => ['admin/user/login'],
        ],
    ],
    'modules' => [
        'admin' => [
            'class' => 'mdm\admin\Module',
            'controllerMap' => [
                'assignment' => 'backend\controllers\AssignmentController',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

and this is the action that i want to extend:

```
namespace backend\controllers;

use mdm\admin\controllers\AssignmentController as BaseAssignmentController;

class AssignmentController extends BaseAssignmentController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $render = parent::actionIndex();
        // Here i want to use the content rendered by parent and add a button near another button
    }
}
```

It seems to me that I use wrong method for this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller gives you access to its view or parent view so you can use it.
For example in your action that was extended:

```
$this->getView();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an "extended" view  you should not perform this action in controller but use the the render for common part in view .. you can see  a how use common part of view code in `update` and `create` view   automatically generated  by gii .. in this views both use a common part of code named  `_form`

eg in  update.php view  you can see  code as

```
<?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
]) ?>

// and add  you new code  
 <?= $form->field($model, 'my_extension_field1')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>
```